# Making a dropdown menu disappear when clicking anything but the menu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new to this site. I've googled for almost 6 days now for javascript to use in making a dropdown menu as seen on Google and Facebook. FB uses it on Account link. When you click on Account in Facebook, a dropdown menu comes out.

This is what I'd like:

When we click anywhere else on the page, it disappears, but it's still displayed when we click on this menu itself e.g. we can logout from the page, but if we click somewhere else, it disappears like some onblur event has occured.

I've written the code like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function dropdown() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("hide");
            if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
            } else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            }
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onClick="dropdown()">Hello Mohd</a>
        <div id="hide" style="display:none">
            <p>Hii All<p></p>Hw r u</p>
            <p><a href="#">Sign Out</a></p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, it works well when I click the link. A dropdown menu appears with all my details and disappears when I click it again. I want it to disappear when we click anywhere else on the page, which I'm unable to do.

If I use onblur then the dropdown menu disappears even when I click on it i. e. I can't use it.

Comment: Have you tried binding a click event to the document?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/vty5s/

Code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Javascript Dropdown Example</title> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            #hide{
                display: none;
                background-color: #68D;  
                border: 1px solid #000;
                width: 80px;
            }
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function showDropDown(e){
                 document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(){};
                 if(e.stopPropagation)
                 e.stopPropagation();   // W3C model
                 else
                 e.cancelBubble = true; // IE model

                 document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";
                 document.onclick = function(e){
                 var ele = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
                 if(ele == document.getElementById("test")){
                     hideDropDown();
                     return;
                 }
                 do{
                     if(ele == document.getElementById("hide"))
                     return;
                 }while(ele = ele.parentNode);
                 hideDropDown();
                 };
            }

            function hideDropDown(){
                document.onclick = function(){};
                document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('test').onclick = showDropDown;
            }
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <a href="#" id="test">Hello Mohd</a> 

        <div id="hide"> 
            <p>Hii All<p></p>Hw r u</p> 
            <p><a href="#">Sign Out</a></p> 
        </div> 

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('test').onclick = showDropDown;
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: hey PaulPro! thanks very very much for ur help. It's exactly as I want. thanks for the work.    but... when i use ur code in my page it doesn't work, I don't know what is going on but it doesn't work at all... I copied all the things & pasted all at the desired places of my page (i. e. script in <script> tag in the <head> tag, css in style tag etc...)  but still when I click Hello Mohd link, nothing happens... plz do something and tell me why it's not working in my page... please reply soon... thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi @Muddser. The problem might be this line of javascript: `document.getElementById('test').onclick = showDropDown;`. It won't work in the head tag since the element `test` doesn't exist yet. Try putting that one line in it's own separate `<script>` tag which is right after the `</body>` tag

Comment: hi @ PaulPro!: hey friend I tried everything but nothing is happening... can't work out what s wrong... it'll be highly thankful to u if you give the total code compiled instead of differently giving css js & html... please help... Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem :) Could you accept my answer by hitting the Checkmark under the vote count for my answer?